# How to specify architecture (platform) flag for Docker images in VS Code Dev Containers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

When I pull a Docker image locally through the command line, I can use the `--platform` flag (as explained [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#options)) to pull an image for an architecture different from the one I'm running Docker on. For instance, I can pull an image for `linux/amd64` even though I am running Docker on `Darwin/arm64`.

Docker desktop is capable of running images for some different architectures using a VM. On macOS for Apple Silicon it does so using QEMU.

When I configure a Dev Container for VS Code, I can specify a Docker image with a particular tag in `devcontainer.json`, but how can I specify the platform/architecture? I can't find any configuration option in the docs for `devcontainer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no direct way to specify platform architecture within the `.devcontainers.json` file, you can use the `dockerCompose` route to achieve your goal. This can be achieved by modifying your config file as below.

```
"dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
"service": "<service-name> in docker-compose file",
"workspaceFolder": "<volume mount> in service",
// "build": {
//  "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
// },
```

then create a `docker-compose.yml` file within the `.devcontainers` folder similar to

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 wta-api:
   build: Dockerfile
   platform: linux/amd64
   ports:
    - 8000:8000 // modify as required
   volumes:
    - ../codebase:/workspace directory
```

You can learn more from the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container#_use-docker-compose)

UPDATE 1: From my experience, it appears that devcontainers uses amd64 by default on Apple Silicon

UPDATE 2: It appears VSCode forces the platform of the container to match the platform of the docker vm, so the only way I was able to achieve this was to create an `X86_64` container environment on M1, for more info on Colima, see [here](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima)